# Flutter vpn Ikev2EAP server

Tags: flutter, vpn

I need a vpn app. I use [flutter_vpn](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vpn) package. Now I don't know what write to `server:`, `username:` and `password:` properties.

```
FlutterVpn.connectIkev2EAP(
                server: ,
                username: ,
                password: ,
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _addressController = TextEditingController();
  final _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
.
.
.
```

and then

```
.
.
.
FlutterVpn.connectIkev2EAP(
   server: _addressController.text,
   username: _usernameController.text,
   password: _passwordController.text,
);
```

Comment: I need real server:)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: just create the free server from vpnjantit.com @SulaymonNe'matov

Comment: Hey everyone I am also stucked there, I tried to create a new server on vpnjaniti.com and also I tried opensource vpn but my app shows connecting and error.